# How to splice the following 2 git commands into one?

Tags: git

The following command changes the working directory, and also the stage:

`git checkout <commit> <file>`

The following command doesn't touch the working directory, it only changes the stage:

`git reset <commit> <file>`

I would like to change only the working directory, but don't want to touch the stage. I can do this with the following commands:

```
git checkout <commit> <file>
git reset <file>
```

How can I do that with a single command?

Comment: You can combine commands inside a bash function, which allows for arguments to be passed into it. In my simple tests, it's not behaving like I'd think, but something like this in your alias config should be a good start:

undo = "!f() { git checkout $1 $2 && git reset $2; }; f"

Comment: in that case I would rather prefer my version... doesn't exist a single git command for this?

Comment: What do you mean by *stage*? The index?

Comment: yes, index==stage, isn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most correct answer is "you can't".  There are two simple work-arounds though (well, the first is simpler than the second, and the second is sort of saying "you can"):

- Use `git show`, e.g., `git show HEAD~3:path/to/foo.txt > path/to/foo.txt`

  The drawback here, besides having to write the file name/path twice, is that the `show` command does not apply any smudge filters.  If you don't *have* any smudge filters, that's no big deal.
- You can choose a different "index file" (staging area) during your `git checkout` so that the stage that's touched is not the stage you'll use for the next commit:

  `GIT_INDEX_FILE=/tmp/dummy git checkout <commit> <path>`

  The drawback here is that this is a bit clumsy, and you should remember to clean up your dummy index-file (the fake staging area).  Also, the above assumes shell (sh/bash) syntax; you may need to use the `env` program, or some other form, in other shells.

Comment: the first work-around is OK, but not "clearly git", the second one... I didn't understand it :) thank you though

Comment: Am I correct in my assumption that `GIT_INDEX_FILE` is used by git to determine the location of the index? That's hacky. I like it.

Comment: @Zeeker: yes, the default setting is `$GIT_DIR/index` where `$GIT_DIR` itself defaults to, well, wherever your git directory is. :-)